# Why do I need to append blank line before markdown tag when embeded within Html tag?

Tags: html, markdown

If I need to embed markdown tag within Html tag, I find only Code A can work well.

The Code B and  Code C  will display orignal text `![Pro.png](:/323475ba602d4c9d8e1b2b75b123efb)` in result window, it seems that the `![Pro.png](:/323475ba602d4c9d8e1b2b75b123efb)` isn't explained by markdown enginer.

How can I remove the blank line before markdown tag when embeded in Html tag ?

**Code A**

```
<div class="myImage">   

![Pro.png](:/323475ba602d4c9d8e1b2b75b123efb)
</div>
```

**Code B**

```
<div class="myImage">   
![Pro.png](:/323475ba602d4c9d8e1b2b75b123efb)
</div>
```

**Code C**

```
<div class="myImage">   
<br/>
![Pro.png](:/323475ba602d4c9d8e1b2b75b123efb)
</div>
```

Comment: "How can I remove the blank line before markdown tag when embeded in Html tag ?"—why do you want to? [It's required (in most implementations) by design](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.31.2/#example-188).